# ¿Por qué al instalar mi APK (en desarrollo) salen 2 iconos en el menú?

Tags: android, android-studio

Lo que pasa es que estoy desarrollando esta app como proyecto, pero al testear en mi celular se instalan 2, ejecuto cualquiera de las dos y aparentemente comparten todo como si solo fuese uno, pero aparecen ambas :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml para que esta pregunta sea de utilidad a la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto, cuando aparece el logo duplicado con Android Sudio, es porque en el manifest seguramente hay 2 `<intent-filter>`

Esto pasa cuando haces 2 activity como modo "Launcher"

Comment: Otra opción para futuros lectores que les haya sucedido lo mismo de esta pregunta es que hayas cambiado tras una configuración el nombre del .apk

Comment: cuando puedas, acepta tu propia respuesta para que, en un futuro, se vea a la primera cuál ha sido la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Existen dos causas para que suceda lo que comentas, visualizar dos iconos de la misma aplicación.

**1)** Realizaste el cambio de tu package name e instalaste nuevamente la aplicación, en realidad se instala la misma aplicación pero su [**id de aplicación**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) (el package name) ahora es distinto.

**2)** La segunda causa es:

**Recuerda que solo debe de existir una actividad que inicia tu aplicación con la siguiente definición del `intent-filter`**:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <!-- Esta actividad es la entrada principal, debe aparecer en el lanzador de aplicaciones.-->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

> [LAUNCHER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) La actividad es la actividad inicial de una tarea y está
>   enumerada en el lanzador de la aplicación del sistema.

---

**El problema que tienes es debido a que tienes la misma definición del `<intent-filter>` en dos `Activity` de tu proyecto.**

Por ejemplo, esto es incorrecto:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".otraActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```